# How is Hydration Mismatch fixed in traditional SPA (CSR apps) like Vue, React, Angular?

Tags: vuejs3, single-page-application, server-side-rendering

I have found on many places what the re/hydration mismatch is but **I struggle to find how is the mismatch resolved** by any of the frameworks listed.

I'm wondering if it **re-renders the whole page** when there is one small mismatch or if it is somehow **capable of just re-rendering the mismatched parts**?

For example when I do not supply the locale parameter to "new Date().toLocaleDateString()" and locales differ per client and server. Will the re-render cause big re-render issue? It's just example, I know it would be better to solve it by suppling the param.

*I would appreciate flow for any listed framework, not just Vue.*